# convert list of lists into nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of list as following

```
l = [( "tx", 'houston', 'richmond'),
("tx", 'dallas', 'lakewood'),
( "tx", 'houston', 'kessler'),
( "tx", 'dallas', 'cedars'),
( "ct", 'hartford', 'wethersfield'),
( "ct", 'hartford', 'parkville'),
( "ct", 'new haven', 'westville'),
( "fl", 'miami', 'gladview'),
("fl", 'orlando', 'parramore'),
( "fl", 'orlando', 'golden heights'),
( "fl", 'miami', 'el portal')]
```

was wondering if there is generic solution from pandas or any other library that will convert the list of lists to nested dictionary, or if someone has written a function that works with multilevel nested data, the number of elements in each set could be more, so what I need is something that keeps iterating and keeps appending until the whole list is lists is converted into nested dictionary
for example

```
{
    "tx": [
        {"houston": [ "richmond", "kessler" ]},
        { "dallas": [ "lakewood", "cedars" ]},
    ],
    "ct": [
        {"hartford": ["richmond", "kessler"]},
        {"new haven": ["westville"]},
    ],
    "fl": [
        {"orlando": ["parramore", "golden heights"]},
        {"miami": ["el portal", 'gladview']},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Look up `defaultdict`

Comment: Seems to be a list of tuples, not list of lists.

Comment: Might also be better if the output 2-letter states mapped to a dict (mapping cities to list of neighborhoods) instead of a list of dicts. For example: `{ "tx": { "houston": [...], "dallas": [...] }, ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a couple lines of code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
for x,y,z in l:
    d[x][y].append(z)
```